# 2D Scatter plot with z-value used for PlotLegends

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, legending

[image: Image source: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wgftu.png]

I have a data set that can be generated as follows:

```
x=RandomReal[{1,5},100];
y=RandomReal[{11,50},100];
z=RandomReal[{7,25},100];
```

For each of the (x,y,z) 3-tuple, I want to make a 2D scattered plot of x vs. y and put a plot legend of **z values** in color bar with the figure as shown in the example image above.

---

I have used

`ListLogLogPlot[Table[{x[[i]],y[[i]],z[[i]]},{i,Length@data], PlotLegends-> Automatic]`

but cannot get what I want. Earlier, I used `ListContourPlot`, it was quite easy there but now I want a scattered plot.

How can I do it?

Comment: `ListPointPlot3D[Transpose@{x, y, z}, PlotLegends -> Automatic]`

Comment: I don't want a 3D plot.

Comment: `ListDensityPlot[Transpose[{x, y, z}], PlotLegends -> Automatic]`

Comment: I have modified the question. I want something like that.

Comment: `BubbleChart[Partition[Transpose@{x, y, z}, 1], 
 ChartLegends -> Automatic]`?

Comment: Not working. The plot legend color bar is not coming as shown in the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`Graphics`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics.html)

```
Clear["Global`*"]

SeedRandom[1];
x = RandomReal[{1, 5}, 100];
y = RandomReal[{11, 50}, 100];
z = RandomReal[{7, 25}, 100];

zRng = MinMax[z];

Legended[
 Graphics[{AbsolutePointSize[6],
   {ColorData[{"SolarColors", "Reverse"}][Rescale[#[[3]], zRng]],
      Tooltip[Point@Most@#, NumberForm[#, {5, 1}]]} & /@
    Transpose[{x, y, z}]},
  Frame -> True,
  FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {HoldForm[x], HoldForm[y]}),
  AspectRatio -> 1],
 BarLegend[
  {{"SolarColors", "Reverse"}, zRng},
  LegendLabel -> Style[HoldForm[z], 14]]]
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you Bob.

Answer (score 3):

```
SeedRandom[1];
x = RandomReal[{1, 5}, 100]; y = RandomReal[{11, 50}, 100]; z = 
 RandomReal[{7, 25}, 100];

BubbleChart[Transpose[{x, y, z}], 
 ColorFunction -> (ColorData[{"SolarColors", "Reverse"}][#3] &)
 , ChartLegends -> 
  Placed[BarLegend[{ColorData[{"SolarColors", "Reverse"}], 
     MinMax[z]}], After]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Add: `, BubbleSizes -> {0.04, 0.04}` if you require all bubbles to be the same size; although, this would instantly defeat the purpose of the bubble chart.